# (irb):4: warning: key "abc" is duplicated and overwritten on line 4

Tags: ruby

Rearrange the key values in the hash below to look like:

```
{"abc"=>"wqeq","dfg"=>"sadsada","qwe"=>"asdad","yui"=>"asdasd","abc"=>"weqqw","qwe"=>"assadsad","yui"=>"asd","dfg"=>"asdsad"}

{"abc"=>["wqeq","weqqw"] ...}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is really unclear at the moment - please add some more info to help people answer this. There's a good guide to formatting questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that assigning a key with the same value as a previous one overwrites it.

As far as I'm aware, there's no code-based solution to solve this; you just need to re-write it with arrays as the keys' values where they're duplicated.

```
{"abc" => ["wqeq", "weqqw"],
 "dfg" => ["sadsada", "asdsad"],
 "qwe" => ["asdad", "assadsad"],
 "yui" => ["asdasd", "asd"] }
```

I guess that's the output you're looking for. If not, please add a little more info to the questions and I / others will be able to help out.

If you want to bring a gun to a knife fight, you can use `compare_by_identity`:

```
hash = {}

hash.compare_by_identity
hash["abc"] = "wqeq"
hash["abc".dup] = "weqqw"

# ... etc ...

puts hash # => { "abc" => "wqeq", "abc" => "weqqw" }
```

... and then process that. Feels kinda dirty to me though.

Comment: In what version does `compare_by_identity` allow the storage of multiple string keys that are equal?

Comment: I wouldn't say they're equal, more it was an option to format a hash with multiple strings of the same (apparent) value, if that was in someway useful to the questioner (it's pretty vague). You think it's unadvisable / misleading here @engineersmnky? I know you know your stuff so will happily edit out if you'd advise it.

Comment: No I am saying you would need to "dup" the second string for this to work. [Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/PepperyTalkativeSparrow). Additionally I certainly would never advise it but it is fun to demonstrate so I have no objection to that

Comment: Ah - I'm with ya. Updated accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @prashant did this help at all?